# unable to fetch array data in datalist using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to fetch data from array in a datalist using Jquery, but its not working. I am getting the data in array correctly. I have tried `forEach` loop, `for` loop and even `while` loop. for `for` and `while` loop, i got the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'while'/'for'

in `$.each` loop, i get the result in one line with comma separated.

Here is my code of fetching and displaying data in array

```
var salesman_datalist = [];
for(var i = 0; i<=10; i++){
    if(data['salesman'][i]){
        salesman_datalist[i] = data['salesman'][i];
    }
}
console.log(salesman_datalist);
```

Here is code for `while` loop

```
j = 0;
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input list="salesmanlist"><datalist id="salesmanlist">'+while(j <= salesman_datalist.length){ + '<option value="01">'+val+'</option></br>'+ j=j+1 } + '</datalist></td>';
```

for `for` loop using its correct syntax
Here is the code of `foreach` loop

```
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input list="salesmanlist"><datalist id="salesmanlist">'+$.each(salesman_datalist,function(val){ + '<option value="01">'+val+'</option></br>' }) + '</datalist></td>';
```

but here i received its result:

```
<datalist id="salesmanlist">usama,0.02,ali,0.01,Ali,,Usama Shakeel,,Haider,0.22</datalist>
```

Comment: `while` is a statement, not an expression. You can't use it as a subexpression.

Comment: @Barmar: so what can be the possible solution or syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()` to iterate over an array, and `.join()` to concatenate the results into a single string.

```
cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input list="salesmanlist"><datalist id="salesmanlist">'+
    salesman_datalist.map(val => '<option value="01">'+val+'</option>').join('<br>') + 
    '</datalist></td>';
```